# Child class won't override parent class?

Tags: python, class, abstract

Folder structure:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    vehicle.py
    car.py
tests/
    test_car.py
```

vehicle.py

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Cannot instansiate abstract class")

    def _speed(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Cannot instansiate abstract class")

    def dashboard(self):
        return  f"speed: {self._speed()}"
```

car.py

```
from project.vehicle import Vehicle

class Car(Vehicle):
    def _speed(self):
        return 100
```

test_car.py

```
from project.car import Car

def test_car():
    c = Car()
    assert(c.dashboard() == "speed: 100")
    assert(c._speed() == 100)
```

test outcome

```
===================================== test session starts ======================================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.2, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/xual/Software/bug
collected 1 item                                                                               

tests/test_car.py F                                                                      [100%]

=========================================== FAILURES ===========================================
___________________________________________ test_car ___________________________________________

    def test_car():
>       c = Car()

tests/test_car.py:4: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <project.car.Car object at 0x7f9d579ca0>

    def __init__(self):
>       raise NotImplementedError("Cannot instansiate abstract class")
E       NotImplementedError: Cannot instansiate abstract class

project/vehicle.py:3: NotImplementedError
=================================== short test summary info ====================================
FAILED tests/test_car.py::test_car - NotImplementedError: Cannot instansiate abstract class
====================================== 1 failed in 0.08s =======================================
```

I'm assuming that car is extending and overriding vehicle.  Everything works **IF** the dashboard method is removed from vehicle.py and test_car.py  What about the setup is wrong?

Comment: The `.dashboard()` method has absolutely nothing to do with this; the test is failing before you even get to a point where you could call that method.  You just need to override `.__init__()` so that the parent's version of that method doesn't get called.

Comment: Use `collections.abc` to define abstract base classes.

Comment: To extend Jasonharper's answer:
Add the following to your Car class:
    def __init__():
        pass

Comment: Get rid of the `__init__()` method in the base class if you don't want to force all child classes to define it.

Comment: @Barmar is correct

Answer (score 0):

I removed the __init__ method from the parent class.

This fixed everything else.  This seems to be the answer to this problem.  I wish I knew more about what was happening in the background how __init__ affects inheritance.